# How to pull the newest object from an array without using first or last?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to pull out the newest post from an array of posts. But using `.first` is messing it up for some reason. For some it is pulling the newest, while for some it is pulling the oldest.

I have: `default_scope order: posts.created_at DESC`

so first should give me the latest post but sometimes it doesn't. Is there a better way to get the newest post?

**Update**

Here is my controller code:

`@users = User.includes(:ideas).order('users.updated_at DESC')`

I want to order users by last updated DESC and then for each user show his most recent post. I think the `default_scope order: posts.created_at DESC` is clashing with `.order('users.updated_at DESC')`

In my view I am doing:

`@users.each do |user|
post = user.posts.first
end`

It's not working right. HOw do I fix this without N+1 problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by `id` if it's incremental:

```
scope :latest, -> { order('id DESC') }
Post.latest.first 
Post.latest.limit(10)
```

One more benefit for relational databases here is that there is an index on id already.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the order clause in the default scope is being overwritten.

You can force the ordering with [reorder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder):

```
Post.reorder(created_at: :desc).first
```

Use it in a named scope:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :latest, -> { reorder(created_at: :desc).first }
end
```

**References:** [`reorder` on Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder)

**Edit for the updated question**

With the default scope defined as below in `post.rb`:

```
default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
```

You can simply write:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user).group('posts.user_id')
```

You will get the latest posts (one per user)

If some posts don't have a user:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:user).select('posts.*, users.username AS user_username, etc........').group('posts.user_id')
```

Each post of `@posts` will get a `user_username` method without the n+1 problem. You can of course define more custom methods depending of what you need.

Comment: Would reorder create an additional query. Because the code is being iterated for each User who has `many_posts` and I am trying to find each users latest post. I have already done `includes(:Posts)`

Comment: Then you should use `joins` instead of `includes` with an order clause on the `posts` table. Something like `User.order('posts.created_at DESC').joins(:posts)`. Feel free to give more details in your question.

Comment: `@posts = Post.includes(:user).group(:user_id)` doesn't work : `PGError: ERROR:  column reference "user_id" is ambiguous`. I am using Postgres and I have user_id as a column in ideas table

Comment: @pratski try `@posts = Post.includes(:user).group('posts.user_id')`

Comment: Nope `column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. I think I read somewhere that you can;t use group and order in the same query. Since order_by is a default scope, group_by won't work in Postgres. Is that true?

Comment: @pratski I have honestly no idea. I am also using PG and never had a problem running `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` in the same query. Can you share the whole project?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
 Post.first(:order => 'created_at DESC')
```

won't work (or are you interested in the most recently *updated*) there's something broken somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

It should be like :

```
Post.order('created_at DESC').first
```